# How to create a price range slider in flutter like this?

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

Would anyone know how to create an Price range slider in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired Range Slider using [syncfusion_flutter_sliders](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders).

It is easy to use and comes with a variety of sliders.
Check this [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/slider/overview) for more info.

Comment: is this package paid one?

Comment: No, it's free..

Comment: useful document brother... thanks!!!